# CFWebsocket Cross Domain?

Tags: coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10

Does anyone know if the new websockets feature in CF10 can be used cross domain and cross server? And does anyone know or have some sample code to do this?
I have a simple live help chat working on my app but I want to apply it to other sites and have one central admin chat area where the support agents will interact with users cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they do not. You can, however, use a `<cfhttp>` to call a file on the other site that will publish the message. Here is I accomplished this.

Create a file called **socketPublisher.cfm** and save it in a directory that does not require a login access a file.

**socketPublisher.cfm**

```
<cfparam name="Request.Attributes.msgType" default="newJob">
<cfparam name="Request.Attributes.channel" default="notify">
<cfparam name="Request.Attributes.Type" default="">
<cfoutput>
<cfswitch expression="#Request.Attributes.Type#">
    <cfcase value="yourType">
        <cfscript>
            WSPublish('chat',{message: '', msgType: '#Request.Attributes.msgType#'});
        </cfscript>
    </cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase>
        <cfscript>
            WSPublish('#Request.Attributes.channel#',{message: '', msgType: '#Request.Attributes.msgType#'});
        </cfscript>
    </cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
</cfoutput>
```

Then in you action page on the other site, you will need to make your http request to that file.

**actionPage.cfm**

```
<cfhttp method="Post" url="#socketURL#/_scripts/socketPublisher.cfm">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="msgType" value="pendingFiles">
</cfhttp>
```

That should do it.

There is also a know issue with CF10 `WSPublish` that it will change the CGI scope cause error when trying to do a redirect from an action page. I am using this as a workaround for that issue until I can find a better solution.